# Guaranteed Profit on a Roulette wheel: Does $N$ exist?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm looking for a good answer that can be explained to someone without much maths.

If a casino spins a roulette wheel enough times, the probability the casino makes a profit $\to$ 1 as $N \to \infty$ (given the green outcomes).

Does this mean there exists a number of spins $N_c$ (somewhere among the integers, but not specified) that guarantees profit?

If $N_c$ is not guaranteed to exist, what does it mean to say the casino is guaranteed to make money?

**Perhaps this is an example of a non-constructive proof (if proven using the proof of the weak law of large numbers)?**

Comment: Have you thought about using Gambler's Ruin to explain this?

Comment: Can a sequence converge to a number without ever reaching that number?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee, but it is verrry likely. 
On average, the bank gets about $\frac1{37}$ of all money wagered (except in the US, where casinoes are cowards and increase their win to $\frac2{38}$). However, an average is not a sure and failsafe prediction. There is *variance* that comes into play here. For sufficiently many games played, both the average win $E$ of the bank and the total variance $V$ of the win grow proportionally to the number of games. However, the *probability* that the total win falls below $E-z\sqrt V$ depends essentially only on $z$. And since $E\sim n$ and $\sqrt V\sim \sqrt n$, it would require larger and larger $z$-values to make $E-z\sqrt V\le 0$. Larger and larger $z$-values occur with lower and lower probability. While it is still possible in theory that the bank falls below $0$ after $10000$ games, the probability is lower than even the most improbable event you can imagine, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

> If a casino spins a roulette wheel enough times, the probability the
>   casino makes a profit → 1 as N → ∞ (given the green outcomes).
>
> Does this mean there exists a number of spins Nc (somewhere among the
>   integers, but not specified) that guarantees profit?

No, it does not.

> If Nc is not guaranteed to exist, what does it mean to say the casino
>   is guaranteed to make money?

Recall the formal definition of a limit at infinity ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_at_infinity)). $lim_{N→∞} P(N) = 1$ means that for any ε > 0, there exists M such that |P - 1| < ε (that is, P > 1 - ε) whenever x > M. In other words: You can pick any number arbitrarily close to 1 that you like, and then there will be a resulting number of spins M that gives you that probability for a profit.

This is not to say that there is any number of spins that gives you probability 1 itself. I would not interpret this as saying that the casino is guaranteed to make money.

> Perhaps this is an example of a non-constructive proof (if proven
>   using the proof of the weak law of large numbers)?

No, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The number $N_c$ that you mention does not exist, since theoretically the player can win $n+1$ times for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The profit is guaranteed in the sense that the expected profit of a single game (which we denote by $EX_1, EX_2,$ and so on) is positive (i.e. $0 < EX_1 = EX_2 = \ldots$). By the strong law of large numbers we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n}{n} = EX_1 > 0 \ with \ prob.\ 1.$$
This means that with probability 1, **at some moment** we will have a (positive) profit.

Comment: You say the "moment" does not exist in the first line, then say its does exist in the final line. Am I correct here?

Comment: Assume for simplicity that we always bet 1 and that guessing a number pays twice. In that setting the player either moves one dollar up or one dollar down.  In case of $N_c$ we would be sure that after $N_c$ games the casino earns money no matter what player bets, no matter where the ball lands. This is impossible because there is a non-zero probability that the player guesses the right number $N_c$ times in a row from the beggining.  On the other hand, by the strong law of large numbers, with probability 1 the number of players losses will exceed the number of his successes in finite time.

Comment: However, this time can be arbitrarily large. Therefore if the casino has only a finite amount of money it can get bankrupt with non-zero probability. Only a casino with infinite budget will benefit with probability 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose using Gambler's Ruin to explain this. Start the argument with first defining what is profit and what is loss to the casino.

For example, I like to say "The gambler leaving with less money then when he came in translates to a profit to the casino." In other words, if the gambler enters the casino with $\$x$ and leaves with any amount $\$x-d$ where both $x$ and $d$ are positive numbers, then the casino has made a profit.

The key to this is explanation is in the wheel. There is no such bet in roulette games where the odds are winning are $0.5$. Betting on colours (red or black) results in the best odds to win, but is still not as high as $0.5$. This, then, can be shown using Gambler's Ruin that in the long run after many bets, the gambler is more likely to walk away with less money then when he started with. In other words, in the long run, the casino will make a profit.

As to how, start with a simple model where the player has $\$3$ and each bet is $\$1$. Fill in the transition matrix. Then, work from there.

Comment: My problem is about the philosophical construction of this "moment in the long run". Does it exist or not?